# Approach to struct inheritance in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

let's imagine the following situation: there's a book with different sections and each sections consists of different paragraphs.

```
strut Book: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var author: String
  var sections: [Section]
}

struct Section: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var label: String
  var paragraphs: [Paragraph]
}
```

Within this paragraphs, there are different types too, so let's say: `ParagraphQuestion`, `ParagraphAsk` and `ParagraphWork`. These paragraph structs have something in common and inspired by other languages, inheritance would be the way to go I guess.

```
protocol Paragraph {
  var id: UUID
  var title: String
  var text: String
}

struct ParagraphA: Paragraph, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var text: String
  var isA: Bool
}

struct ParagraphB: Paragraph, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var text: String
  var isB: Bool
}

struct ParagraphC: Paragraph, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var text: String
  var isC: Bool
}
```

The second problem is, I don't how the best practice looks like to render those different paragraphs. According to the above example, a section object would have a property called `paragraphs`, that consists of one or more objects of those different paragraph structs. To achieve it, maybe a parent-protocol would be a proper solution, that has all the shared properties of each `Paragraph*` struct.

At the end a `switch/case` in the view template would decide which child view to render, based on the object type at the specific index at the current iteration.

```
var label: String
@Binding var paragraphs: [Paragraph]

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(paragraphs.indices) { index in
                    switch type(of: paragraphs[index]) {
                      case ParagraphA.Type:
                          ParagraphAView(
                              paragraph: self.$paragraphs[index]
                          )
                      case ParagraphB.Type:
                          ParagraphBView(
                              paragraph: self.$paragraphs[index]
                          )
                      case ParagraphC.Type:
                          ParagraphCView(
                              paragraph: self.$paragraphs[index]
                          )
                    }
                }.foregroundColor(Color(.darkText))
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Image(systemName: "plus").padding(8))
            .navigationBarTitle(label)
        }
        
    }
```

At the moment, I'm not able solve the error **Failed to produce diagnostic for expression** occurring at the returning **body** view

Any other approaches to solve this situation? Would it be better to have one "big" struct with all shared properties required and `isA`, `isB` and `isC` as optionals?

Thank you very much in advice!

Comment: You need to clarify your question there is a lot going on. Also structs are value types and do not have inheritance. You can either create protocols that they can conform to with default implementations or you could use classes if you require inheritance.

Comment: Okay, I will edit my question, so hopefully my point gets more easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

> These paragraph structs have something in common

That suggests a protocol, but you'd need to explain what that "something" is. It may also suggest composition (HAS-A rather than IS-A). It may also suggest an enum. It really depends on what these look like.

In Swift, however, inheritance should generally be your last choice. There are definitely reasons to use it, and it's fully supported. But is not the preferred way to do things. (You'll notice very little inheritance in stdlib. That's on purpose.)

> and inspired by other languages

You should be very careful before allowing that to influence your design in Swift. Different languages have different patterns that make sense. There's an old saying that you can write FORTRAN in any language (but you shouldn't). If you take each word of an English sentence and translate them into Spanish, the result may be comprehensible, but it'll be horrible Spanish. The same is true of computer languages. Think about your problem and solve it in Swift. Don't try to transliterate some other language into Swift.

How to render the paragraphs will depend strongly on the problem. The paragraphs could know how to render themselves into a context (like a UIView and a CGContext), or they could just be data and some renderer might know how to render them (like an NSAttributedString and a CTFramesetter). Both approaches are sensible. It depends how you expect your program to evolve in the future. Do you expect there to be more kinds of paragraphs or more kinds of renderers in the future?

If you're uncertain, start by just making each type a struct that represents itself in the most obvious way (don't worry about rendering or methods). If you can't think of any data the struct absolutely needs, let it be an empty struct to start with. Then write the renderer based an initially-empty "Renderable" protocol. Whenever the renderer needs some information, add a method or property to the protocol. Then create extensions on your structs to conform to the protocol. This is not always the right design, but if you don't have another approach, it's decent starting point to explore the problem.

---

Your Paragraph protocol looks fine, but your `isX` booleans don't make a lot of sense. Is there any case where a `ParagraphC` wouldn't return `isC == true`? You're just reproducing the type.

In the example you've given, however, all your structs have precisely the same structure (id, title, text), and the only difference seems to be how they're rendered. If that's the case, then they just need a property that indicates how they're rendered. One way to do that would be an enum. That would look like:

```
struct Paragraph: Identifiable {
    enum Kind {
        case a, b, c
    }
    let id = UUID()
    var kind: Kind
    var title: String
    var text: String
}

struct ParagraphView: View {
    var paragraph: Paragraph

    var body: some View {
        switch paragraph.kind {
        case .a:
            ParagraphAView(paragraph: paragraph)
        case .b:
            ParagraphBView(paragraph: paragraph)
        case .c:
            ParagraphCView(paragraph: paragraph)
        }
    }
}

...

            ForEach(paragraphs) { paragraph in
                ParagraphView(paragraph: paragraph)
            }
```

Now maybe your Paragraphs have different properties, so you really do need a protocol:

```
protocol Paragraph {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var text: String { get }
}

struct ParagraphA: Paragraph, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var aStuff: String
}

// ...
```

Then ParagraphView might look like:

```
struct ParagraphView: View {
    var paragraph: Paragraph

    var body: some View {
        switch paragraph {
        case let p as ParagraphA:
            ParagraphAView(paragraph: p)
        case let p as ParagraphB:
            ParagraphBView(paragraph: p)
        case let p as ParagraphC:
            ParagraphCView(paragraph: p)
        default:
            EmptyView() // You must handle every case
        }
    }
}
```

And the loop would need to call out `\.id` since a protocol can't be Identifiable.

```
            ForEach(paragraphs, id: \.id) { paragraph in
                ParagraphView(paragraph: paragraph)
            }
```

If there were many paragraph types (or they were likely to change over time), then the ParagraphView switch statement could become unwieldy, and there are other techniques you could start to use, generally by wrapping things in AnyView. For example:

```
protocol Paragraph {
    ... existing ...
    func makeView() -> AnyView
}

struct ParagraphA: Paragraph, Identifiable {
    ... existing ...

    func makeView() -> AnyView { AnyView(ParagraphAView(paragraph: self)) }
}

struct ParagraphView: View {
    var paragraph: Paragraph

    var body: some View {
        paragraph.makeView()
    }
}
```

There are many other approaches. Deciding the best one depends on your exact situation, how many paragraph types there are and how they're likely to change over time. There's no single best practice here. But a switch statement like in ParagraphView is probably fine.

(The reason you're having compilation problems is that your current switch statement doesn't handle all cases. It just falls through if the type isn't one of the ones given. You can't do that in SwiftUI; you must handle every case. But the compiler isn't always very good about giving helpful error messages. The best way to find what's going wrong is to split things into smaller Views, like I did with ParagraphView.)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Napier! I edited my question again, maybe it's more clearly what I try to achieve! 

What do you mean by "renderable" protocol? So I guess you mean, every paragraph should be it's own struct, even if alls struct definitions have some properties in common, like above within my question?